# How to check the message WM_KEYDOWN can be translated into the message WM_CHAR or not in the WM_KEYDOWN handler?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, keyboard

I am working on a feature that I need to check the message WM_KEYDOWN can be translated into WM_CHAR or not. If yes, I need to send the char(that translated by WM_KEYDOWN) to another process in the WM_CHAR handler; else, I need to send the key scan code to another process in the WM_KEYDOWN handler.
Actually, I have found a solution:
Refer the description of TranslateMessage in MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644955(v=vs.85).aspx
Translates virtual-key messages into character messages. The character messages are posted to the calling thread's message queue, to be read the next time the thread calls the GetMessage or PeekMessage function.

From the above text, if the WM_KEYDOWN can be translated into a WM_CHAR message, the message WM_CHAR will be in the thread message queue already when the WM_KEYDOWN handler is called.
It means that I can call PeekMessage in the WM_KEYDOWN handler and check the message is WM_CHAR or not. If yes, I should do nothing in the WM_KEYDOWN handler and send the char in the WM_CHAR handler; else, I should send the scan code in the WM_KEYDOWN handler. My code:

```
MSG_WM_KEYDOWN(OnKeyMessage)
MSG_WM_SYSKEYDOWN(OnKeyMessage)
MSG_WM_KEYUP(OnKeyMessage)
MSG_WM_SYSKEYUP(OnKeyMessage)

MESSAGE_HANDLER_EX(WM_CHAR, OnChar)

void
MyWindow::OnKeyMessage(UINT nChar,     // IN: VK_* code
                       UINT nRepCnt,   // IN
                       UINT nFlags)    // IN
{
    MSG msg;
    PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);
    if (msg.message == WM_CHAR) {
        return;
    } else {
        ...
        /* Send scan code */
        ...
    }
}

LRESULT
MyWindow::OnChar(UINT uMsg,     // IN
                 WPARAM wParam, // IN
                 LPARAM lParam) // IN
{
    ...
    /* Send the char (UINT)wParam */
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

I test some cases in my local machine. But I think this solution is too tricky. Is there any common solution?
Appreciate!

Comment: You can have a stab at it with ToUnicodeEx().  Beware that this will never be completely reliable, keyboard state is a per-thread property.

Comment: Why not send scan code when `WM_KEYDOWN` arrives, and then also send the character code when `WM_CHAR` arrives a short while later? Do you really need to look ahead?

Comment: Thanks your comments, Igor. The reason is that it will generate duplicate characters. Such as, press the key 'a' will generate two messages: WM_KEYDOWN and WM_CHAR. If I send both scan code in WM_KEYDOWN handler and unicode WM_CHAR handler, it will generate two characters 'a' in the remote application.

Comment: Hi, it's an old thread but did you find a satisfactory solution to your problem?